# trying to read quadratic programming problem in cplex, get error

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am trying to load a CPLEX LP file in to CPLEX using the "read" command.  I believe that in this problem, I have a set of constraints that are quadratic.  But, from what I understand CPLEX will still attempt to solve quadratic programming problems.

However, when I try to read it in, I get this error:

```
CPLEX Error  1437: Line 284: Illegal quadratic constraint sense.
```

Is there something special I need to do to read in a quadratic programming problem?

NOTE: I am able to load this LP file in to scip and solve it using: scip -f

Comment: Looks like a programming problem. Is there not a computing website where this question would be more clearly on-topic?

Comment: I can try stackoverflow, but I figured more math users would be likely to use cplex

Comment: This is pretty much off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

CPLEX solves only convex optimization problems.  No math programming instance with a nonlinear equality constraint can be convex, so cplex will refuse to attempt to solve any problem with such a constraint.